# Multiline grep to find variable (constructor) definitions recursively

Tags: regex, linux, bash, grep

How can I create a multiline grep across all files inside a directory that prints out the string in between both patterns including the patterns themselves?

I tried to use several variants, but I'm kind of stuck with the RegExp matching multiple lines.

```
grep -RPzo "var Class = (.*) \};" ./
grep -RPzo "var Class = function\(\{(.*)\};" ./
```

The grep command should look up all files recursively and print out all the contents in between (and including) "var Class = " and the first "};" that occurs after it, which might be after several line breaks. Is this possible using grep only (and not pcregrep)?

The first pattern for the definition of the JavaScript function works fine, so that's where I'm stuck:

```
grep -RPzo "var Class = function\((.*)\)\s\{" ./
```

An example definition of the content that should be matched (to try out things more easily):

```
var Class = function(data, game) {

    var settings = lychee.extend({}, data);

    this.foo = { x: 0, y: 0, z: 0 };


    this.setFoo(settings.foo);

    lychee.game.Bar.call(this, settings);

    settings = null;

};
```

Comment: See http://nixtip.wordpress.com/2010/10/12/print-lines-between-two-patterns-the-awk-way/ ... don't miss the comment section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or use gAWK!

```
{
   if( $0 ~ /\{/ )
      cbo++;
   if( $0 ~ /\}/ )
      cbo--;
   if( cbo == 1 && $0 ~ "^([[:space:]]?+)(.+)([[:space:]]+)\\{$" )
      rec=1
   if( rec == 1 )
      buff = ( buff ? buff "\n" : "" ) $0
   if( cbo == 0 )
      rec=0
} END {   
   if( cbo == 0 )
      print buff
   else 
      print "Dude something funkey goes on with ur input... " cbo " brackets are left open!"
}
```

Example:
http://pastebin.com/TTCHBPvm

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would think of using `sed`:

`sed -n '/start-marker/,/end-marker/p' <(echo -en "first line\nstart-marker\notherline\nend-marker\nmore\na")`

This command will match and print lines from `start-marker` until it match `end-marker`.

You still have to adapt it for your patterns but sed should do the trick for you.

for clarity the one line echo outpu this:

```
echo -en "first line\nstart-marker\notherline\nend-marker\nmore\na"
first line
start-marker
otherline
end-marker
more
a
```

I made it work with this sed command:

```
sed  -n '/var Class =/,/^\};/p' /tmp/sample
```

Note that I use `^\};` to match a bracket at the start of the line other wise it was stopping at this line `this.foo = { x: 0, y: 0, z: 0 };`.

Answer (score 0):

With **grep**.

I am not sure I understand your question, but your solution works find.
You just need some minor changes in the regex:

```
grep -RPzo 'var Class = function\((.|\n)*?\n\};' ./
```

- `(.|\n)*?` in order to be possible to have linebreaks (as less as possible=not greedly)
- `\n\};`  to get the tipical end function